# How to find difference between to dates

Tags: java, android, date

I have two dates with string format "16-Feb-2017", "26-Feb-2017"
and I used

`SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");`

but I am unable to get exact result like "10".

Comment: What do you mean by "exact result like '10' " ??? Please modify your question or atleast add some explanation...

Comment: Do you mean you need the difference between two dates in days?

Comment: `but I am unable to get exact result like "10".` - 10 what? seconds? years? Date and Time is measured in miliseconds in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.pass your dates in myDate and time_ago.

```
int totalMin;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

Date systemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        String myDate = sdf.format(systemDate);


Date Date1 = null;
try {
    Date1 = sdf.parse(myDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Date Date2 = null;
try {
    Date2 = sdf.parse(time_ago);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

assert Date2 != null;
assert Date1 != null;
long millse = Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime();


long mills = Math.abs(millse);

Hours = (int) (mills / (1000 * 60 * 60));
Mins = (int) (mills / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
Secs = (int) (mills / 1000) % 60;

long diffDays = millse / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

if (Secs >= 60) {
    Mins = Mins + 1;
    Secs = Secs - 60;
} else if (Mins >= 60) {
    Hours = Hours + 1;
    Mins = Mins - 60;
}

totalMin = (int) ((Mins) + (Secs / 60));
String t_time;

if (diffDays > 0) {
    if (diffDays == 1) {
        t_time = diffDays + " day";
    } else {
        t_time = diffDays + " days";
    }

} else if (Hours > 0) {
    if (Hours == 1) {
        t_time = Hours + " hour";
    } else {
        t_time = Hours + " hours";
    }

} else if (Mins > 0) {
    if (Mins == 1) {
        t_time = totalMin + " minute";
    } else {
        t_time = totalMin + " minutes";
    }

} else {
    if (Secs == 1) {
        t_time = Secs + " second";
    } else {
        t_time = Secs + " seconds";
    }

}
```

Comment: When input is like `16-Feb-2017` without any hour or minute, I wouldn’t expect hours, minutes and seconds to be needed in the output. The original asker can best tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
java.time.LocalDate d1 = java.time.LocalDate.parse("16-Feb-2017", formatter);
java.time.LocalDate d2 = java.time.LocalDate.parse("26-Feb-2017", formatter);

Period until = d1.until(d2);
System.out.println("Dif: " + until.getDays());
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ... This is not applicable in android, can u please help me suitable with android

Comment: This is the recommended way for anyone who can use Java 8 (or later). I am upvoting to help guide any readers who can.

Comment: Beware the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")` uses the default format locale for the computer. If you need some other locale, you may add a `Locale` argument.

Comment: You are right, Ole V.V. concerning the Locale.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to init SimpleDateFormat.

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ...
I need a difference between 2 Dates...Please let me know how can I proceed

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in a comment, use Java 8 `java.time` classes if you can. [kamehl23’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42268099/5772882) shows you how. It’s a both elegant and robust solution, also across changes to and from summer time (DST).

EDIT: Stuck with an older Java version, they say you can use either [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) or Joda time, I haven’t tried any of them. ThreeTenABP, I read, is an Android adaption of a backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7, so I would be tempted to give that a shot.

You *can* of course get through with Java 1.1 `Calendar`. The solution that also works across summer time change is:

```
    String formattedDate1 = "16-Feb-2017";
    String formattedDate2 = "26-Feb-2017";

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", YOUR_LOCALE);

    Date d1 = df.parse(formattedDate1);
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(d1);

    Date d2 = df.parse(formattedDate2);
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(d2);

    int daysBetween = 0;
    while (cal1.before(cal2)) {
        daysBetween++;
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    System.out.println(daysBetween);
```

This prints `10`. It’s neither very elegant nor very efficient, but it works robustly as long as the ‘from’ date is before (or the same as) the ‘to’ date (which can easily be checked).